# MySQL 8 - optimize all tables + indexes

Tags: mysql, index, optimization, mysql-8.0

I have a bunch of tables (InnoDB) within several databases (MySQL 8), that I run Garbage Collect scripts on, on daily basis, removing stale records that are no longer needed.  All tables do have indexes on them.

Would it make sense / be at all beneficial to optimize all tables, say every week, to increase performance?  If so, is there are good command to run, to do so?

I tried doing

```
sudo mysqlcheck -o --all-databases
```

But get the following error message:

```
note     : Table does not support optimize, doing recreate + analyze instead
status   : OK
```

Comment: looks like this command does the trick  mysqlcheck --auto-repair -o --all-databases

Comment: How much does the "Garbage Collect" remove? Do you have a metric you are increasing? Is there some aspect of query performance that is poor unless you perform this `mysqlcheck -o`?

Comment: Hey Dan, GC rotates all of the data in the table, every week (ie - if there are 100k records, they are slowly deleted out, and new ones are written in).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't bother.  InnoDB mostly takes care of itself.  `OPTIMIZE` temporarily squeezes out some wasted space, but new waste occurs as inserts/etc happen.  The performance benefit of `OPTIMIZE` is next to nil.

Answer (score 1):

Those messages are normal for InnoDB. You can continue doing so.

The InnoDB Storage Engine performs `OPTIMIZE TABLE mydb.mytable;` like this

```
ALTER TABLE mydb.mytable ENGINE=InnoDB;
ANALYZE TABLE mydb.mytable;
```

I have mentioned this over the years:

- `Sep 27, 2015` : [How can I defragment tables in MySQL?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/116255/how-can-i-defragment-tables-in-mysql/116263#116263)
- `Jun 24, 2015` : [guideline for calling optimize table after alter table?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/105052/guideline-for-calling-optimize-table-after-alter-table/105055#105055)
- `Feb 27, 2013` : [What is the difference between optimize table and analyze table in mysql](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/35520/what-is-the-difference-between-optimize-table-and-analyze-table-in-mysql/35523#35523)
- `Aug 04, 2011` : [Optimizing InnoDB default settings](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/4303/optimizing-innodb-default-settings/4325#4325)

I recommend doing analyze daily or weekly

```
sudo mysqlcheck --analyze --all-databases
```

Then, do the optimize once a month or once a quarter.

Comment: Thank you for the response.  Is there a good way to ALTER TABLE / ANALYZE TABLE  (InnoDB's equivalent of OPTIMIZE) with one command, for all tables in a database?

Comment: It’s in my answer